# О способе словообразования

Tags: словообразование

Каков способ образования слов: трезвучие, звукоряд, полутон, разнообразие?

Я думаю, сложение. Верно ли?

Answer (score 2):

> …я думаю, сложение, верно ли?

Не совсем верно.  Сложением основ образованы слова ***звукоряд*** и ***полутон***.

***Трезвучие*** и ***разнообразие*** образованы по-иному:

***трезвучн***ый -> трезвуч-**иj**-е

***разнообразн***ый -> разнообраз-**иj**-е

**Способ образования: *суффиксальный с усечением производящей основы ("н").***

Comment: а разве трезвучие не сложено из слов три и звук (звучание) ??

Comment: Нет, это трезвук образовано сложением, а трезвучие - суффиксально